# build a Json object using StreamingJsonBuilder (Groovy)

Tags: json, groovy

how can I make StreamingJsonBuilder return a String instead of an array

example:

the input is:

```
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter()
StreamingJsonBuilder builder = new StreamingJsonBuilder(writer)

builder {
    id object.items.id
}
```

the output should be :

```
"id": [
        "12345"
    ]
```

What I'm expecting is :"id": "12345"

Comment: I use this object def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper()  so I can parse the Json file:                                                                                   def object = jsonSlurper.parseText(getData('input.json'))

Comment: What method are you calling on the `builder` and what output is that call producing?

Answer (score 0):

to have array of values use array

```
import groovy.json.*
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter()
StreamingJsonBuilder builder = new StreamingJsonBuilder(writer)

def object=[
    items:[
        [id:111,txt:"--111--"],
        [id:222,txt:"--222--"]
    ]
]

builder {
    id( object.items*.id )
}

println writer
```

returns `{"id":[111,222]}`

Comment: he wanted rather `id object.items*.id`